# How get screen dimension on Android SDL2.0 NDK C?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, sdl-2

In my program in SDL I must get screen size.
How I can to do it?
On android I cant use

```
error: initializer element is not constant
 int height = Android_ScreenHeight;
```

is possible initialising it in ndk?

Answer (score 1):

You can get screen buffer size :

```
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
  ...

  ANativeWindow* window = state->window;
  ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;

  // Try lock buffer
  if (ANativeWindow_lock(window, &buffer, 0) < 0)
    return;

  LOGI("buffer info: width = %d height = %d", buffer.width, buffer.height);

  // Unlock buffer
  ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(window);

  ...
}
```

I know you can also get screen info through other NDK stuff, but this works!

Comment: this is not SDL ? I must write my own main function? not int main( int argc, char * args[] )
I must set this new main function to activity?

Comment: Hmmm, I was assuming you were in "pure" ndk (defining your own "main" function). If you're using C as library for java, it's a bit different, but the main thing is to get the android_app* state somewhere. Then you'll get almost everything you want.
Or you can call Java through Java Native Interface (JNI). But it's not convinient and quite ugly.